# Parsing large XML file (1.8GB) to JSON

Tags: node.js, json, xml, parsing, large-files

I'm trying to parse an XML file into a JSON file in my node project. For parsing smaller files, I've always used 'fast-xml-parser'.

The file I'm dealing with now is way larger, so large in fact that is exceeds the available memory. Because of this issue I have to use a parser that supports piping. I've looked online and found one called 'sax' but for as far as my understanding goes it doesn't parse into JSON.

I tried putting the 'fast-xml-parser' into a listener that 'sax' provides like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import sax from 'sax';
import { XMLParser, X2jOptionsOptional } from 'fast-xml-parser';

const parserOptions: X2jOptionsOptional = {
    ignoreDeclaration: true,
    ignoreAttributes: false,
    removeNSPrefix: true,
    attributeNamePrefix : "",
    transformTagName: (tagname) => camelize(tagname),
    transformAttributeName: (attributeName) => camelize(attributeName),
    updateTag: (tagName, jPath, attrs) => {
        if (tagName == 'placemark') return 'placemarks';
        if (tagName == 'timeStep') return 'timesteps';
    }
}

const parser = new XMLParser(parserOptions)

const saxStream = sax.createStream(false, {
    trim: false,
    lowercase: true,
    xmlns: true,
    position: false
})

saxStream.on('data', (data) => {
    const parsed = parser.parse(data)
    fs.writeFileSync('src/forecast/forecast.json', JSON.stringify(parsed))
})
```

When using the above listener, the first chunk of data gets parsed and put into the json file, after that, an error is thrown:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addChild')`

Does anybody know how I can parse the data chunks into one JSON file?

Comment: If you want "streaming" but to "materialize" a certain element node as XML you could then feed to your fast-xml-parser check whether https://www.npmjs.com/package/xtreamer helps. It is not clear how your input is structured and what kind of output JSON you want but at least that API seems to help to process a certain definable node as XML further with your existing parser.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(parsed)` this requires the entire json in memory and the entire data set in memory at the same time.  I don't know if there's a streaming json option in Node

Comment: Is this still open?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js unfortunately isn't very well supplied with XML tools. You could use the sax.js parser but it involves some low-level programming and it certainly won't handle the conversion to JSON, you would need to program this yourself.

Does this job actually need to run under node.js? If you were able to run under Java or C# you could write a streaming XSLT 3.0 transformation and run it using Saxon-EE [disclaimer: my company's product]. The SaxonJS product, which runs under node.js, doesn't offer streaming.

Another possibility you could consider is to use sax.js to split the large file into many small XML files, and then process these using non-streaming utilities such as fast-xml-parser.